# Why isn't my 'UIDatePicker' displaying properly?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uitextfield, uidatepicker

I am using the following syntax in a View Controller (using a Storyboard) to adapt an existing UITextField to a date format.

```
@IBOutlet weak var productTimeRemainingField: UITextField!

private var datePicker: UIDatePicker?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePicker?.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime
    datePicker?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(newProductViewController.dateChanged(datePicker:)), for: .valueChanged)

let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(newProductViewController.viewTapped(gestureRecognizer:)))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    productTimeRemainingField.inputView = datePicker
}

@objc func viewTapped(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    view.endEditing(true)
}

@objc func dateChanged(datePicker: UIDatePicker) {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
    productTimeRemainingField.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
    view.endEditing(true)
    if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
          datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .compact
      }
}
```

The above code is working, and allows me to select both a time and date, however when the field is selected, the section where a user selects the time and date is shown right at the bottom of the page, making it nearly impossible to properly make a selection.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening, and how I can fix this so it is shown in the centre of the View Controller (as with the majority of other apps - see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0os7.png) for my objective.

This is a screenshot as to how the date picker currently appears - [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NS77O.jpg).

Comment: For context - the UITextField I am using has died constraints and is appearing in the intended position both before and after a date selection.

Answer (score 1):

**1st solution:**

1. You need to set the frame as per your need.
2. Set preferredDatePickerStyle after initialization

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        datePicker = UIDatePicker()

        //---Changes---
if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
            datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .compact
          }
        datePicker?.frame = .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
        //---

        datePicker?.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime
        datePicker?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dateChanged(datePicker:)), for: .valueChanged)

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(viewTapped(gestureRecognizer:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        productTimeRemainingField.inputView = datePicker

    }
```

**2nd solution:**

1. Set preferredDatePickerStyle after initialization
2. use preferredDatePickerStyle as **wheels** and remove the frame, it will be more user friendly.